# Finding $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]/(p)$ for some prime $p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra

I have to prove that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]/(p)\cong \mathbb{F}_{p^{2}}$ if $p\equiv 5\ \text{mod}\  6$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]/(p)\cong \mathbb{F}_{p}\oplus\mathbb{F}_{p}$ if $p\equiv 1\ \text{mod}\ 6$. We are suppose to need that $-3$ is a quadratic residue mod $p$ if and only if $p\equiv 1\ \text{mod}\ 6$.

I think it is easy to show that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-3}]/(p)$ has $p^{2}$ elements. Maybe we could solve the problem trying to find when $(p)$ is a maximal ideal, but I am not able to do it.

Any help would be appreciated.

(It is exersise 0.13 in Reid's "Undergraduate commutative algebra")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]/(p) \cong \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z[X]/(X^2+3)$.

Now it should become clear how to use the knowledge for which primes $-3$ is a quadratic residue $\mod p$.